# Largest cube that fits between spheres.

Tags: geometry, optimization, contest-math, spheres, solid-geometry

Two spheres, one of radius 2 and the other of radius 4, have the same centre. What is the edge size of the largest cube that fits between them? (AMC Senior, 2015)

diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMuix.jpg

I tried taking a cross-section of the shape, and used Pythagoras but kept getting the (same) wrong answer. The answer is $\frac {2}{3}(\sqrt 22 - 2)$.

Comment: If you want to argue with a cross-section, the easiest seems to be a section along a plane that contains the centre, the point where the cube touches the inner sphere and a point where the cube touches the outer sphere. In such a section, _the cube doesn't become a square_ (I don't know whether that is your mistake, but it seems like an easy one to do and not discover).

Comment: Oh right I believe that was the error that I had made. Could you explain why that is the case?

Comment: The section of the cube has two sides that are edges of the cube and two sides that are diagonals of the faces of the cube, and thus $\sqrt2$ times longer (at least, that's what I think... It might not be a rectangle either, however in which case I don't know off the top of my head what it should be).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To elaborate on Michael Rozenberg's answer, we can let $x$ be the side length of the cube, and draw a right triangle. One vertex, A, is at the center of the spheres. The second, B, is at the center of the outermost face of the cube. The third, C, is at one of the vertices of the cube that touches the outer sphere.

AB contains a radius of the inner circle and also extends through the center of the cube, so it has length $2+x$. C is on the outer sphere, so AC has length $4$ (this is the hypotenuse). BC extends from the center of a face to one of that face's vertices, so it is half of the diagonal of a square of length $x$. Thus it has length $\frac {\sqrt 2}2x$. From the Pythagorean theorem, we have:

$$(x+2)^2+\frac 12x^2=16$$

Here's a rough sketch:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just
$$(x+2)^2+\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt2}\right)^2=4^2$$

Comment: Yeah that's what I did, but why did you use $\sqrt 2$ in the fraction? @Michael Rozenberg

Comment: @oscquito Because the diagonal of the square with side $x$ is $x\sqrt2$, but for Pythagoras using we need $\frac{1}{2}\cdot x\sqrt2=\frac{x}{\sqrt2}$.

Comment: So which three lengths did you use for Pythagoras? Sorry I'm a little confused @Michael Rozenberg EDIT: Never mind, someone else explained.

Comment: @oscquito $OMA$, where $O$ is a common center, $M$ is a center of the square with vertex $A$. The plain of this square is a tangent plain to the sphere with radius $2$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the largest such cube has side length $s$.  The face of the cube whose vertices lie on the larger sphere is a square inscribed in a circle of some radius which we will call $r_1 = s/\sqrt{2}$.  How far is this face from the center of the spheres?  Well, we know that the outer sphere has radius $4$, and the circle formed by the intersection of this sphere with a plane some distance $d$ from the center is simply $$r_1 = \sqrt{4^2 - d^2},$$ from which it follows that $$d = \sqrt{4^2 - r_1^2} = \sqrt{16 - s^2/2}.$$  But it is evident that if the edge length is $s$, then the plane containing the opposite face of the cube is parallel to the plane through the outermost face and is separated by $s$.  But this "inner" plane is by definition a distance $2$ away from the center.  Hence we have the relationship $$s + 2 = d = \sqrt{16 - s^2/2},$$ or $$\frac{3}{2} s^2 + 4s - 12 = 0,$$ or $$s = \frac{2}{3}(\sqrt{22} - 2),$$ as claimed.